# Which version of VLC is right for an Exynos tablet?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, vlc, arm-processors

VLC has [two versions listed for ARM,](https://nightlies.videolan.org/)

- Android (ARMv7-A)
- Android (ARMv8-A)

I'd rather not install with the PlayStore. Both of these versions when downloaded say "Can't open file" when I click then in the File Manager.

For comparison, I also download [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/) clicking it open up a prompt for me to install with the option `INSTALL` and `CANCEL`. I am using a Samsung SM-P600 UD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## -ARMv7.apk

The version needed with `-ARMv7.apk`. After downloading that, you have to install it. This may be more difficult than need be because VLC currently has the content-type on the response set wrong, you can read more about that here:

- [Can not install apks from File Manager or browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197184/7425)

**You may  open the file downloaded from the Download Manager nor through the browser -- see the link above**