# Can not install apks from File Manager or browser?

Tags: installation, apk, lineageos, vlc

In the answer to this question I specifically discovered that I could not install the [VLC nightlies](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196341/7425). It had nothing to do with that answer, which was on a question about which version of VLC was right for that device. But that question was in fact inspired by this problem: I never previously had an APK I couldn't install by merely downloading, when I am in the Android Web Browser, and it downloads the APK, I can click on it in the notification applet at the top. When I do, it says

> Can not open file

When I open that file up with the LineageOS Files Manager, `com.android.documentsui` I get the same error. Now, I'm wanting to know what specifically is borked about *just* the VLC packages? Does anyone else get this problem? Why is that `pm install ./appname.apk` in the shell works, but the GUI doesn't?

I'm using LineageOS 14.1-20180616, based on Android 7.1.2.

Comment: Have you allowed installing from unknown locations in the settings menu?

Comment: @Ankush yep, it worked for installing probably tens of apks, this is some kind of problem that I'm kind of sure is either specific to the apk being malformed, or to filemanager, or the apk-parsing library. Don't know where to start except to say, I installed f-spot through the browser just fine. I don't think the browser/file manager is spawning right to `pm`, because that works.

Comment: It is possible that the content/media type for the apk file is set wrong, so the file manager does not know the type of the file (as in it may be ignoring the extension, and relying solely on the media type (application/vnd.android.package-archive).

Comment: @Ankush I've update with a url to the apk, you're welcome to take a look at the package and see if anything pops out at you. If you can help identity the issue, I'll file a bug, because I'm thinking it is one, I just don't do much android dev.

Comment: I would try another file manager just to be sure, then file as a bug. I can't try to install it on my device, as my phone does not have an ARM processor.

Comment: this question really requires someone with extensive packaging experience on Android/apk, I think I'd look harder if there was nothing obviously out of place there, I'll wait to see how to trouble shoot these problems and if someone smarter can save me some time shooting in the dark on this.

Comment: @EvanCarroll v3.0.11 installs fine, but I had your same (random) issue a while ago, with apps completely unrelated to each other. In my case, it was a LineageOS regression, so try updating to the latest weekly before retrying the installation.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I'm using LineageOS, but I'll try right now -- my version is pretty new.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman no joy, now I'm using June 16 LineageOS 14.1 and it's still not working.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman figured out and self-answered.

Comment: @Ankush figured it out and self-answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Installing

### With the  LineageOS File Manager

It seems that inside the File Manager, there are two discrete things `Download` a directory, and `Downloads` some broken nonsense shortcut link:

- **Does not work:** On the left nav, you'll see `Images` `Videos` `Audio` `Recent`, and then `Downloads` `Documents`, and `SM-P600`. Installing from the `Downloads` on the right bar, gives this error.
- **Works**: Going into the device at the bottom of the left nav (which is actually just a link to `/data/media/0` and then clicking on `Download` will take you `Download` which is actually different from `Downloads` (plural and on the Left Nav). From this you can install the APK.

### With the CLI

- Enable ADB in the Settings
- Run `adb shell` on the host
- Browse to `/sdcard/Downloads` or `/data/media/0/Download` with `cd`. If you're unsure where the apk is located try running

  ```
  find / -name 'VLC*-ARMv7.apk
  ```
- Locate the apk and install with `pm`

  ```
  pm install ./VLC*-ARMv7.apk
  ```

## The problem

The problem seems to be that VLC web server answers the request with a response that has `content-type: application/octet-stream` like this,

```
$ curl -s -I "https://nightlies.videolan.org/build/android-armv7/VLC-Android-3.0.11-20180618-0249-ARMv7.apk" 
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.15.0
date: Tue, 19 Jun 2018 03:16:06 GMT
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 25048251
last-modified: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 06:05:02 GMT
etag: "5b274b8e-17e34bb"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-clacks-overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```

Rather than `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. This means that you can't install through the browser, or the *Downloads* shortcut. This is because APK files are just zip files:

```
$ file VLC-Android-3.0.11-20180618-0249-ARMv7.apk 
VLC-Android-3.0.11-20180618-0249-ARMv7.apk: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

So what the File Manager and browser are trying to do is open them as such -- and you don't have something that hands `Zip archive data` 2.0+