# APK's AndroidManifest.xml looks to be binary

Tags: files

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my unzip tool, or not but I'm looking into the APK file structure and I see a file called `AndroidManifest.xml`. Inside that file there is no XML? It actually looks like a binary dump,

What does this file do, and should it look like this.

I'm using the official VLC nightly, [I'm trying to troubleshoot this problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197175/7425)

- https://nightlies.videolan.org/build/android-armv7/VLC-Android-3.0.11-20180618-0249-ARMv7.apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems AndroidManifest.XML is a binary xml file, here is a tool to extract [Binary XML](https://github.com/ytsutano/axmldec). You can confirm that by using `file`

```
$ file AndroidManifest.xml 
AndroidManifest.xml: Android binary XML
```

Answer (score 1):

apktool can decode the binary XML format, and much more: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

It is available in many repositories, for instance on Ubuntu: `apt install apktool`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Indeed, `apktool decode app.apk` works fine.